# TextView Hint messes up RTL gravity

Tags: android, layout, textview, right-to-left

I have a layout with textviews.
Whenever I use Left to Right locale **OR** remove the android:hint elements, it works properly. However, in RTL (Hebrew locale) with LTR value (English text) and gravity="start" or "end" it just pushes the text into a hint sized text view in the wrong direction. Maybe it will be clearer with examples:

LTR locale and text:

[image]

RTL locale and LTR text with hints - here the "Data A" field with gravity "end" pushes it to the right instead of left because it is English. "Data B" has gravity "start" so it is the same case, only reversed:

[image]

the hints are an important issue because when I remove them, then wrap_content will shrink the view and the layout constraints do their job and it shows up correctly even in RTL

Here is the same example with android:hints removed:
[image]

LTR layout editor:
[image]

basically, my question is how to make the gravity of a textview always work towards the end or the start of the locale, and not the language of the text

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/LogEntryListViewItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"><!--TODO-->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/LogEntryListSelectedFieldField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/LogEntryListSelectedFieldField"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DataB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Number"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LogEntryListItemDateTimeField"
        style="@style/LogEntryListItemDateStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/LogEntryListSignedField"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LogEntryListItemAircraftField"
        style="@style/DataA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/DataB"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/DataB" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/DataA"
       style="@style/LogEntryListItemAircraftNameStyle"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="end"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/LogEntryListItemDateTimeField"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LogEntryListItemDateTimeField" />

   <android.support.constraint.Barrier
       android:id="@+id/barrier"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:barrierDirection="bottom"
       app:constraint_referenced_ids="LogEntryListItemAircraftField, DataA" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/LogEntryListItemNotesField"
       style="@style/LogEntryListItemNotesStyle"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:hint="(Notes)"
       android:maxLines="2"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/DataB"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/LogEntryListItemDateTimeField"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier" />

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/LogEntryListSignedField"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:scaleType="center"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_edit"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: no it's not the maxLines since it should look like in the first screenshot and use the entire area

Comment: but the first words on the second line are very short ("xc xfxfx..."). why isn't "xc" in the first line?

Comment: what is the width of that view which has xc xfxfx text ?

Comment: it's in the xml file - LogEntryListItemNotesField. basically the entire width.

Comment: ok never mind it was my mistake - it had line feeds...

Comment: No - I was just referring to the notes multiline wrap issue which I mentioned in the comments. The main issue with the gravity of RTL locales still exist

Comment: shouldn't make a difference. remove the styles if you'd like. they only consist of android:textStyle, textSize and textColor

Comment: Check my answer I believe this is what your are looking for. It's working fine while changing rtl or ltr directions.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it on my device and it's working alright. Please check and see how it works out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/LogEntryListSelectedFieldField"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:text="20"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/LogEntryListSelectedFieldField"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DataB"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="Data B"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LogEntryListItemDateTimeField"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
    android:text="Hercules (C-130)"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/LogEntryListSignedField"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/LogEntryListItemNotesField"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LogEntryListItemAircraftField"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="Hercules (C-130)"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Number"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/DataB" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DataA"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end|center"
    android:text="Data A"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/LogEntryListItemDateTimeField"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/LogEntryListItemDateTimeField"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LogEntryListItemDateTimeField" />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="bottom"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="LogEntryListItemAircraftField, DataA" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LogEntryListItemNotesField"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:hint="the hints are an important issue because when I remove them, then wrap_content will shrink the view and the layout constraints do their job and it shows up correctly even in RTL"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/LogEntryListItemDateTimeField"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Number"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/barrier" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/LogEntryListSignedField"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_edit"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```